# how to read a subset of a csv file from s3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to read a csv file from s3 using `boto3` as shown in the following code:

```
import boto3
from itertools import islice

obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name)
    data = csv.DictReader(
    islice(StringIO(obj.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")), 10)
)
```

The problem is that the csv file is too large and my computer doesn't have enough memory to upload it (that's the reason why I'm trying to read a subset) and `islice` seems to load the whole file before getting the subset, so the memory is still crashing.

How can I upload only a subset of the csv file using `boto3`?

Comment: Use the fact that the response body is a StreamingBody. See [here](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html). You can use iter_lines to get an iterator to yield lines from the raw stream. Alternatively, but probably less useful, is that you can request specific byte ranges from an S3 object (e.g. bytes 12000 to 21456) - probably not that useful to you in this case, but be aware of it.

Comment: Either specify a range, or download the whole file to your local drive and use [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read through the file without loading it all into memory.